# Is it always possible to eliminate all Geopanels?

Tags: disgaea-4

From what I have seen you need the same number of geoblocks as you have different geopanels. N-1 colored blocks (where N is the number of different color panels) and a Null block. I have seen levels with only N-2 blocks (plus the Null block) though. Are they impossible rooms or is there just an alternate solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sometimes not possible to eliminate all geopanels by using the initially provided blocks.  However, you can use the geo change ability to randomize them and hopefully complete the change with the new layout.